# Issue centering form inside body | HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have this as part of my script, the header and 2 paragraphs are being centered properly, but container and button are off to the left side. I have tried using `<center>` `</center>` but I don't know where to properly apply them for the form and button to be centered.

Screenshot of what needs to be centered:

[image: Screenshot of what needs to be centered]

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">

  <h1>Header Text</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <form action="excel-script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="file" name="excelDoc" id="excelDoc" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="submit" name="uploadBtn" id="uploadBtn" value="Button" class="btn btn-success" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also add your css please?

Answer (score 1):

Add 'text-center' class to the row and edit the 'col' classes to have 12 as a sum

```
<div class="container" >
    <form action="excel-script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="row text-center">
           <div class="col-md-2"></div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="file" name="excelDoc" id="excelDoc" class="form-control" />
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
               <input type="submit" name="uploadBtn" id="uploadBtn" value="Button" class="btn btn-success" />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3"></div>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost, button is now on the right but the distance between the form group and button is too far . The form group needs to be brought closer to the right

Comment: Look how I changed now

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>Header Text</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>

<div class="container">  
  <form action="excel-script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">        
        <div class="custom-file" id="customFile" lang="es">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">
            Choose file...
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-1">
        <input type="submit" name="uploadBtn" id="uploadBtn" value="Button" class="btn btn-success" />
      </div>
    </div> 

  </form>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.